# Most efficient way of taking a subset of lines

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files. One huge one (200.000+ lines) called 'db' and one big one (15.000+ lines) called 'indices'.

What is the quickest way of filtering out the lines in 'db' containing any index (anywhere on the line) from 'indices'

The solution I could think of is

```
for index in $(cat indices); do
  grep $index db >> selection
done;
```

but this is taking a long time.

Is there a faster approach in bash, linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fgrep -f indices db
```

should be faster.

Comment: "fgrep" usually isn't the fastest grep variant. You may find egrep is faster still.

Comment: Are you sure about it?